# Визуальный редактор графического интерфейса для tkinter

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, поиск-программ, tkinter-faq

Пожалуйста можете посоветовать визуальный редактор графического интерфейса для tkinter кроме Visual Python Tkinter IDE.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И можно ли в "Blend for Visual Studio 2015" сделать?

Я использую  Python 3.4.4

Comment: вы хотите ui designer/builder типа [Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-using-qt-quick-designer.html) или [Deco IDE (React Native)](https://www.decosoftware.com/), но для Tkinter?

Comment: да gui designer/builder

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Is there a GUI design app for the Tkinter / grid geometry?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14142194/4279) упоминает [Pygubu](https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu), [PAGE](http://page.sourceforge.net/html/intro.html), [Rapyd-Tk](http://www.bitflipper.ca/rapyd/)

Comment: Может Rapyd-tk?Я сам не пользуюсь ,но слышал.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Актуальные инструменты

#### [PAGE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/page/) ([документация](http://page.sourceforge.net/html/intro.html))

- позволяет создавать интерфейс перетаскиванием компонентов;
- на основе "нарисованного" интерфейса генерирует python модули;
- фактическое размещение компонентов с помощью метода `place` (по координатам).

[image: Скриншот PAGE]

---

#### [Pygubu](https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu)

- визуальный редактор графического интерфейса;
- размещение компонентов не перетаскиванием, а выбором ячейки контейнера (сетки) и выбором нужного компонента
- созданный интерфейс сохраняется в собственном xml формате (с расширением ui), полученные файлы в своей программе можно "подключить" для создания окон;
- размещение компонентов с помощью метода `grid` (по сетке).

[image: Скриншот Pygubu]

---

#### [Tkinter-Designer](https://github.com/ParthJadhav/Tkinter-Designer)

- генератор кода и изображений для графического интерфейса на основе дизайна, разработанного с помощью [Figma](https://www.figma.com);
- в сгенерированном коде элементы управления размещаются с помощью `place`.

[image: Tkinter-Designer]

---

#### [Formation](https://github.com/ObaraEmmanuel/Formation)

- визуальный редактор интерфейса
- размещение компонентов перетаскиванием
- описание интерфейса сохраняется в своем xml формате (подход схожий с Pygubu)
- размещение элементов возможно через `grid`, `pack`, `place` (выбирается в свойствах контейнера - окна или фрейма - перед добавлением компонента).

[image: Formation Studio]

---

### Устаревшие, неактуальные, неподдерживаемые инструменты

#### Rapyd-tk

IDE с визуальным редактором графического интерфейса. Поддерживает Python 2.6-2.7. Больше не разрабатывается (ориентировочно с 2014 года). Страница проекта в архиве: [ссылка](https://web.archive.org/web/20191125025228/http://www.bitflipper.ca/rapyd/)

[image: Скриншот Rapyd-tk]

---

#### [Visual Python Tkinter IDE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/visualtkinter/)

Не разрабатывается с 2010 года.

[image: Visual Python Tkinter IDE]

---

#### [SpecTcl](https://sourceforge.net/projects/spectcl/)

Визуальный редактор графического интерфейса с генерацией кода на tcl и других языках. На sourceforge последние изменения были [в 2011 году](https://sourceforge.net/p/spectcl/code/commit_browser), похоже, что больше не разрабатывается.

Comment: Это как закрывашка для дубликатов?

Comment: @0xdb можно и так сказать. Вообще как бы ответ на вопрос, но почему-то кажется что нет смысла давать необщий ответ. Лучше пусть будет как закрывашка с возможностью дополнения, если вдруг появятся новые визуальные редакторы.

Comment: Отличная работа, спасибо!

Comment: Можно было сделать необщим на пару дней, а потом переделать в общий.