# Визуальный редактор GUI Tkinter

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

Всем привет!

Какие есть программы под linux  для визуального создания интерфейса? Умею создавать программы в Tkinter. Нашел генератор интерфейса PAGE.

Сейчас у меня есть задача выводить около 20 графиков(matplotlib) и отображать на них данные. Эти данные будут считываться с файла.

Хочу реализовать задачу при помощи Tkinter. Что можете посоветовать что бы сделать проще и лучше?

Comment: похожий вопрос [Визуальный редактор для tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/650158/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[python-QuickUI](https://github.com/sonvoque/python-QuickUI)

По ссылке библиотека (модуль) для быстрого построения графиков на tk и matpolib. Описание на английском.