# Как создать красивый GUI на Python?

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, pyqt, kivy

Возможно это уже избитый вопрос - как создать GUI на Python. И всё-таки. Я бы не хотел использовать PyQt и PySide (не устраивают условия лицензии), а Kivy не очень нравится. Есть ли ещё библиотеки для Python GUI? Я собираюсь создать приложение для Android. Мне лично нравится TKinter. Можно ли в TKinter указать стили элементов (кнопок, надписей и т.п.)? Или существует способ использовать Figma для Python? Существует ли альтернатива Qt Designer для Python?

Я буду очень благодарен за полезный ответ!

Comment: По поводу Figma, можно посмотреть [Tkinter-Designer](https://github.com/ParthJadhav/Tkinter-Designer)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Визуальный редактор графического интерфейса для tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/650158/1365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам не сильно нравится, kivy есть kivymd, в данном фреймворке все виджеты стилизованы. Также скоро выйдет программа kivymd builder. Он будет работать как qtdesigner. Вот ссылка на гитхаб проекта:

https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMDBuilder

Также сам фреймворк активно поддерживается. Каждую неделю выходят множество обновлений.

Ну, если всё-таки вы не изменили своё, мненение о kivy и kivymd. То я нашёл ещё одну, это eel, хотя я честно скажу, мне eel полностью не нравится, он не поддерживает, многооконность и в нём слабо реализована асинхронность.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!