# Удобный способ позиционировать элементы Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Потихоньку начинаю изучать тему из заголовка. Начал с Tkinter, есть ли способы легко позиционировать элементы в окне? А то подбирать эти числа пикселей в .place() знатно утомляет. В моем представлении должны существовать какие-то приложения, в которых можно двигать элементы и получать значения, которые нужно ввести в параметры. Спасибо.

Comment: https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu, https://github.com/ParthJadhav/Tkinter-Designer, https://visualtk.com/ это первые несколько вещей, которые нашлись по запросу "tkinter visual designer"

Comment: Если вопрос именно про визуальный редактор интерфейса, то см. [Визуальный редактор графического интерфейса для tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/650158/1365)

Answer (score 1):

В tkinter есть три способа позиционировать элементы,- place по координатом, grid аналог таблицы, pack присоединение с сторон.

Comment: Эти методы просят значения отступов в пикселях, а я бы хотел найти способ перемещать их просто мышкой на манер графических редакторов. Я не уверен, что такое возможно, но вдруг...

Comment: Хотя я почитал про grid, вроде вполне удобно. В любом случае спасибо.

Comment: @НикитаПавлов вроде glade для tkinter, wxformbuilder для wx, qtdisigner для qt. аналогов для kivy я не встречал.

Comment: @ganz glade - для GTK (PyGTK). Для tkinter вот тут практически все какие существовали и существуют на данный момент перечислены: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1192311/1365